# How to specify where a DOM element is allowed to be?

Tags: c#, xml, parsing, dom

I'm creating an extensible XML-like language that will be parsed in C#. When a user creates a new tag, they need to be able to specify where it's allowed to be. i.e., which elements it can be contained in, whether or not it needs to appear before or after a particular element, or where-ever. I want as much flexibility as possible. As an example:

```
grid {
    row {
        if(x='y') {
            "hello"
        } else {
            "world"
        }
    }
}
```

"rows" can only appear in "grids", and "elses" can only follow "ifs".

I'm thinking I could use some jQuery-like syntax, but I don't know quite how that would work. The query `grid > row` would *select* all rows contained in a grid, but could I use that same syntax to indicate that a row is only allowed to appear there? Maybe I could run the selector, and if the element in question is not contained within the resulting set it's disallowed?

Any suggestions on a nice clean way of specifying where elements are allowed to be is appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

That looks a lot like what [XML Schemas](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XML_Schema_%28W3C%29) were created to do.

Comment: How would you specify element X must follow element Y? I thought you could only indicate an element must be contained in another, but not anything to do with ordering?

Comment: http://www.w3schools.com/Schema/schema_complex_indicators.asp This `sequence` thing...? Could that be used to do what I asked? Anyway, I want to specify this information in the C#... I'm trying to get away from XML, not closer to it (I find it way too verbose).

Comment: I understand, then xml is not the thing for you.